# Render to a layer of a texture array in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, textures, render-to-texture, shadow-mapping

I use OpenGL 3.2 to render [shadow maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_mapping). For this, I construct a framebuffer that renders to a depth texture.

To attach the texture to the framebuffer, I use:

```
glFramebufferTexture2D( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, shdw_texture, 0 );
```

This works great. After rendering the light view, my GLSL shader can sample the depth texture to solve visibility of light.

The problem I am trying to solve now, is to have many more shadow maps, let's say 50 of them. In my main render pass I don't want to be sampling from 50 different textures. I could use an atlas, but I wondered: could I pass all these shadow maps as slices from a 2D texture array?

So, somehow create a [GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Array_Texture) with a DEPTH format, and bind one layer of the array to the framebuffer?

Can framebuffers be backed for DEPTH by a texture array layer, instead of just a depth texture?

Answer (score 3):

In general, you need to distinguish whether you want to create a layered framebuffer (see [Layered Images](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Layered_Images)) or whether you want to attach a single layer of a multilayered texture to a framebuffer.

Use [`glFramebufferTexture3D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glFramebufferTexture.xhtml) to attach a layer of a 3D texture (`TEXTURE_3D`) or array texture to a framebuffer or use [`glFramebufferTextureLayer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glFramebufferTextureLayer.xhtml) to attach a layer of a three-dimensional or array texture to the framebuffer. In either case the last argument specifies the `layer` of the texture.

Layered attachments can be attached with `glFramebufferTexture`. See [Layered rendering](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Layered_rendering).

Comment: Could you expand on this a bit more? You wrote (abbr. mine) "Use X to attach a layer of a 3D texture ... to a framebuffer or use Y to attach a layer of a three-dimensional texture to the framebuffer", which really sounds like the same thing, except for "a framebuffer" vs. "the framebuffer".
I am really struggling to see the difference between glFramebufferTexture3D() and  glFramebufferTextureLayer().